# Unable to install Quandl under R version 3.2?

Tags: r, quandl

I'm running R version 3.2 because it is a requirement for ggplots2.

However it seems that I cannot install package "Quandl".
I'm getting the following warnings:

```
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
```

and some others. The result is:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Quandl’ had non-zero exit status
```

My assumption is that the newer R version is not yet supported by the required dependency.

What should I do?

Comment: What part of **Configuration failed because libcurl was not found** is unclear? As for _What should I do?_ how about **exactly what the message says**: install  `libcurl4-openssl-dev` (or if you're on another OS flavour use the package listed in the unquoted remainder of that message).

Comment: 1. * installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found.    I also tried to install libcurl but with the same error message.

Comment: > install.packages("libcurl4-openssl-dev")
Installing package into ‘/home/oliver/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
[Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘libcurl4-openssl-dev’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1 RC)]

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` and reflect a little over the difference between _operating system-level packages_ and _application language packages_.  They aren't the same.

Comment: Thank you Dirk. Yes, works fine now. Sorry but new to R and Linux.

Comment: ggplot2 doesn't require R 3.2, it requires at least 2.14.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `libcurl4-openssl-dev` **operating system** package. You can use this command on Debian-based OS (including Ubuntu and Mint):

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```