# Error installing "Quandl" in R 3.1.1

Tags: r, quandl

I have installed R 3.1. and RStudio 1.0.44 in BunsenLabs (Debian Jessie)

and I want to install the `Quandl` package.

In R console I write:

```
install.packages("Quandl")
```

and the output is:

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing 

ERROR: dependency ‘openssl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing

ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘Quandl’
* removing

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Quandl’ had non-zero exit status

library(Quandl)

Error in library(Quandl) : there is no package called ‘Quandl’
```

Thanks,
RTA

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579938/unable-to-install-quandl-under-r-version-3-2

Comment: Yes I have done it and it doesn't works, also after **install.packages("Quandl")** it outputs: 

Installing package....

(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

also installing the dependencies ‘openssl’, ‘httr’

Answer (score 0):

Solution, write in linux terminal:

**sudo apt-get install r-cran-openssl**

Thanks

Comment: that package is not found

Comment: It was my solution Dec 2 2016, now I use Windows so I can't help you.

Comment: the solution has changed.. it's in the error's output now